# Java: Lossy Image Compression Algorithm

Tags: java, compression, image-compression

My web application allow the user to upload their image to view, and I want to compress the image before display them. What are good lossy image compression algorithm out there. I research around and this page here http://www.imageoptimizer.net/Pages/Home.aspx, does it perfectly. My image was 670KB and after the compression, it was only 150KB and the quality are almost the same.

Comment: JPEG did include some very serious mathematical minds to get it going, you do not say anything about losing or not the quality. JPEG does have a lot of properties to tune. imageoptimizer is a well know suit w/ quite a few optimization, they still return jpeg, though.

Comment: @bestsss: Sorry for being vague. What I try to accomplish is that the compress hopefully dont degrade the image too much and reduce the size of it. I think I will try to follow @Uriah suggestion and try `javax.io`. Thank you

Comment: @bestsss That is a good point, there are ways of reducing the file size of an image by stripping out data that you are not interested in. For most run-of-the-mill JPEG images from a digital camera you might have 10-30K in EXIF data. Pro images may contain ICC profiles that can be several hundred K in size. XMP data added by Photoshop can be heavyweight too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is the de facto compression algorithm for photographic images.

For line-art type images it's common to use PNG or GIF format.

Comment: Please excuse if what I about to say sound stupid, but the web site I shown above, actually reduce the size of a JPEG image from 670KB to 150KB. Is there some open source algorithm like that out there?

Comment: JPEG filters have the concept of 'quality' -- you can adjust a geek-knob to get best quality vs. size compression level for your application. You can take an existing JPEG image (technically a JFIF container) and apply JPEG compression again. There are lots of JPEG implementations available in Java -- some are better then others. Most people find `javax.imageio` to be sufficient. Going (much) further, you could look into fractal compression techniques.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into `javax.imageio` now. Hopefully this is what I want. +1

Comment: The imageio work. I got it working correctly. Thank you. You have the `javax.imageio` answer as one of your comment, can u please revised your original to have the `javax.imageio` name in there as well. Thank you.